# PlayN and Firefox issues

Tags: facebook, firefox, gwt, game-engine, playn

I am working on a pet project of a Facebook game.

I've had a couple of problems until now on Firefox browser.

- CPU runs wild when you start a game on FF.
- TextLayout gets moved a
  few pixels up.
- Caching ruins reloading of resources

Anyone had these kind of problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is why TextLayout is moved up:
[FF bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=737852)

Also after a lot of googling it seems that drawing on canvas has performance issues in FF.